# I am having trouble sending Laos's eVisa form, could I apply on an airport via Visa On Arrival?

Tags: covid-19, laos

I am having trouble sending Laos's eVisa form, could I apply on an airport in Laos (Wattay airport) via Visa On Arrival?

I use Israeli passport and I am coming from Thailand. The passport has more than 5 empty pages and is valid until year 2025.

From reading the Wikipedia article "[Visa Policy of Laos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Laos#Visa_exemption)" I understand that Israel passports are eligible to be stamped for 30 days visa on arrival.

Are there any problems doing this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, as far as I'm aware all visitors eligible for e-Visa are also eligible for visa on arrival.  Just bring exact change in USD if you can and a passport photo (although this seems to be optional for at least some entry points, I wasn't asked for one at Vientiane Wattay airport in 2022).